# Why style.display = 'block' works only on Firefox?

Tags: apex, visualforce, browser, doctype

I'm using the code below :

```
<apex:outputPanel id="myID" style="display: none;">
...
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:commandButton value="Display" onclick="display()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function display() {
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.myID}').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

This code works fine with Firefox but not with IE, Safari or Chrome.

I found that `Doctype` may be the problem but I don't know how to solve this issue.

I tried to add `doctype` attribute on `<apex:page>` tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: How about quotes for the block? `style.display = "block";`

Comment: do you see JS any error in  IE, Safari or Chrome?

Comment: @mast0r : sorry it was a mistake, I use `'`. I updated my post.
@AtulRajguru9 : nothing ! And if I manually set the `display: 'block'` in the console, my panel appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not having a rerender attribute in the commandbutton your whole page may be refreshing, causing you to not see the JavaScript update.

As a temporary fix try putting `reRender="nothing"` in your commandButton. Where 'nothing' is a non existent HTML id. You can change it to a valid id as well if you want to.

Below works fine on FF,Chrome and IE11

```
<apex:page >
<apex:outputPanel id="myID" style="display: none;">
Hello World
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:form>
<apex:commandButton value="Button" onclick="display()" rerender="nothing"/>
</apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display() {
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.myID}').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tried and my panel doesn't appear ! Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? The above piece of code works exactly as it is. Try it separately by creating a new page.

Comment: I tried your code as it is and it doens't work ! I don't know why !

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is very easy: you need to "cancel" any further actions after clicking on the button. Just add `return false` after calling your function on the button:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Display" onclick="display(); return false;"/>
```

Without that the page will be reloaded after clicking on the button, because you dont have `action` parameter:

> If an action isn't specified, the page simply refreshes.

Doc: [Apex CommandButton Action parameter](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

Comment: I tried and my panel doesn't appear ! Thanks.

Comment: @SF_user For me works well in IE9. You may have some other elements on the page that are corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:outputPanel>`'s default behavior is to create a `<span>` in HTML. It could be you're having a problem by trying to make an inline component behave like a block. Depending on the content inside a `<span>` it can sometimes misbehave (like putting block elements inside of it).

If you change the your outputPanel to use `layout="block"`, you will get a `<div>`, which might behave in a more friendly way when you go to modify the CSS dynamically.

So try it like this, instead:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="myID" style="display: none;">
...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work ! Thanks.